# Multilingual sign boards for public and private structures in USA

Tags: design, language, structure, instructions

As there are many languages spoken in the USA, do you recommend to have multilingual sign boards created for parks, zoos, museums, restaurants, stores, libraries, offices etc?

Multilingual sign boards languages with English, Spanish, German, French etc.

Comment: Multilingual signs are generally encountered only if there are languages other than English spoken by a significant percentage of the population in an area - thus, you are more likely to encounter signs including Spanish, Haitian, Urdu, etc., in New York City than you are in (for example) Lincoln, Nebraska.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Are they available for Parks, Zoos,Museums, Garages, Stores, Restaurants, Libraries, Sports grounds, Offices, Educational institutions etc? Which are the Multilingual languages for the sign boards?

Comment: Which languages are used will depend on the particular languages heard in a given region - for example, people speaking Haitian are more likely to settle in  New York than in San Francisco, so signs using Haitian are more likely to be found in New York than in San Francisco. Bahasa Indonesia, on the other hand, is more likely to be found in Los Angeles or San Francisco than New York or Boston. Whatever the languages, multilingual signage will be used wherever a business owner or the local government feels it to be appropriate.

Comment: Remember that the United States, as a single country, is as large in both area and population as all of Europe - and it is at least as diverse as Europe.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Are the Multilingual Signs already implemented in public & private places or they are yet to be implemented in USA?

Comment: They are _widely_ implemented, and have been for _decades_. In some cases, there are governmental mandates for them (and those governmental mandates generally specify the minimum required set of languages); in others, it's at the discretion of the organization posting the sign.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your inputs.